# edge triggered epoll events in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I am writing this FileDecriptor class (inherited from t.i.abstract.FileDescriptor) to listen to events from some file in /sys.

Unfortuantely it can only be used with Epoll's edge-triggered mode. So I am currently using some hackish solution to modify my file descriptor in the epoll list after adding it:

```
self.startReading()
self._reactor._poller._control(_epoll.CTL_MOD, self.fileno(), _epoll.IN|_epoll.ET)
```

Is there a nicer way to do this? Will this introduce any problems (e.g. is it possible that Twisted will remove the ET flag again at some point)?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that Twisted will remove this flag again.  As you can see by the profusion of `_`s in your example, you're using tons of private APIs here, and they may all change without warning.

However, there's no public interface to do what you want.  In my opinion, it is a kernel bug if an interface *requires* the use of a specific sycall interface to query its read/write readiness (like epoll) rather than following some general rule that works with `epoll`, `select`, `poll`, etc.  My first inclination would be to file the bug against the linux kernel.  However, if the kernel folks won't fix it, and you would like to contribute a patch with unit tests to expose a public interface for such linux+`epoll`-specific things to Twisted, please feel free to open a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing to note is that the epoll file descriptor is itself supported by the epoll mechanism.

If you really need to monitor another descriptor in a specific way that the epoll reactor does not support, you can create your own epoll file descriptor, configure it however you want, and then ask the epoll (or select, or poll, or even gtk) reactor to monitor your epoll file descriptor for you.  When the reactor says your epoll file descriptor is readable, then you can do a zero-timeout epoll_wait on it to learn what it wants to tell you.

This is already fully supported by Twisted, all you need to do is implemented the `IReadDescriptor` interface as a wrapper around your epoll file descriptor.

Comment: Interesting. You mean using the fileno() function of an epoll-object in my ReadDescriptor? I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

8 years later, this is still the top of the search results on ET EPoll with twisted, so here's the solution I settled on.  Note that this is "off label", as it's an extension to twisted itself.  Don't pester twisted's authors for help if you break it.  First the code:

```
from twisted.internet.epollreactor import EPollReactor
from select import EPOLLET, EPOLLIN, EPOLLOUT

class EPETReactor(EPollReactor):
    epflags = EPOLLIN
    def addReader(self, reader):
        try:
            self._add(reader, self._reads, self._writes, self._selectables,
                      self.epflags, EPOLLOUT)
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EPERM:
                self._continuousPolling.addReader(reader)
            else:
                raise
    def startET(self):
        self.epflags = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET
    def stopET(self):
        self.epflags = EPOLLIN
```

Note that this still reaches into twisted's non-public APIs a bit, but it lets you do so in one place, no matter where all you need to add ET FDs.  If twisted's internals change enough to break your code, you only need to fix it here.  Also, there won't be any edge cases with events not triggering because the event arrived between when you added the FD and when you set it to ET mode.

Also note that we don't just force ET mode all the time, so that you can configure whatever FDs you need *before* switching to ET mode.

#### Use Case

If you're reading from a socket via `MSG_PEEK` and only half the header has arrived, the choice is between busy-spinning on the socket and using edge triggered mode (or reading from the socket and figuring out how to send the fragment along with the file-descriptor to its destination, but that is not always possible).